# Get Height and Width of a child layout in contraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout in which there is a child layout (frame_layout). The width and height are set as 0dp with match_constraint. How can we get the height and width of this frame_layout once the layout is loaded on the screen ? Using layoutparams gives 0dp. getWidth or getHeight again gives 0dp.

Comment: match constraint will adapt the size based on screensize so it should have size of views did you tried to get width and height after oncreate method complete. Or use delay to get value in oncreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```